# Problem in photo gallery

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

On the iPhone I would like to display images of size 60 * 60 at a time, with 3 of them on each row. I've managed to get the first row with 3 images, but I'm having trouble with the rest. Here is what I have so far:

```
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(20, 10);
for (int i = 0; i < mNoOfPoses; i++) 
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setImage:[self getImageFromName:[mImgArr objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTag:i];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(displayImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 60, 60);
    startPoint.x += 40 + btn.frame.size.width;
    if ( i % 4 == 3 ) 
    {
        startPoint.x = 20;
        startPoint.y += 40 + btn.frame.size.height;
    }
    [mScrollView addSubview:btn];
}
```

this code is showing only 8 images while the number of images is 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want...

```
i % 4 == 0
```

The mod will be 0 for every 4 items.